# Context being lost when passing values as typed values

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm fairly new to typescript and while I've been getting on ok with it, I've came across an issue I can't seem to find a solution for.

I'm trying to pass some data through as below within my react application

```
form = ({handleSubmit, handleChange, handleBlur, values, errors}) => {
```

typescript rightly complains that these are not typed values, but the only way I can use them and satisfy the linter is.

```
form = (handleSubmit: any, handleChange: any, handleBlur: any, values:any, errors:any) => {
```

This unfortunately leaves me with the values that I'm expecting to be defined as undefined, as its then no longer gone through destructuring.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `{}` while `destructuring` the `props` in the second case where the type `any` is added. The following should fix that

```
form = (
 { //The object destructuring in action
    handleSubmit,
    handleChange,
    handleBlur,
    values,
    errors
 } : { //Here goes the type declaration
    handleSubmit: any,
    handleChange: any,
    handleBlur: any,
    values:any,
    errors:any
}) => {
   // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: As referenced above, If I add the {} back in I can't satisfy the linter or typescript generally, the second example is the only way I can get the code to compile.

Comment: @Knade I have updated the answer. This should keep typescript happy.